# Retrieving images from database after uploaded using cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

> use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

$websites => TableRegistry::get('Websites');

$query => $websites->find()->order(['creation_date' => 'DESC']);

> ```
>   echo "<table>";
>     echo"<tr>
>            <td>Cover Image</td>
>            <td>Company Name</td>
>            <td>Date Added</td> 
>          </tr>";
>     foreach ($query as $row) {
>     echo"<tr>
>           <td>".$row['Website']['image']."</td>
>           <td>".$row->company."</td
>           <td>".$row->creation_date."</td>            </tr>";
>     }      
>  echo"</table>";
>
> ?>
> ```

```
      I remember this code in cakephp2 and display the images path "app/webroot/img/websites/"
```

> ```
>     <?php echo $this->Html->image('websites/' . $row['Website']['image']);
> ```

But how to do it in cakephp3 , to display the image.
 ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to not know your real problem. Your question seems to be of someone struggling with the right HTML code to upload images. For that you just have to give to that uploading field in database table columna varchar type and then in the view where to upload the image from a file type to that field. Something like:

```
<div class="form-group">

       <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('your_column_name', [ 'type' => 'file']); 
        ?>
</Div>
```

But if your question is about not being able to retrieve or send to index.ctp or to a frontend view the uploaded image, then your solution is here:
[How to retrieve in cakephp3.7 the name as string of an image uploaded trough a form with blob column into a mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57333785/how-to-retrieve-in-cakephp3-7-the-name-as-string-of-an-image-uploaded-trough-a-f/57478584#57478584)

Answer (score 0):

In cakephp 3 there has no any big difference, It's simple like as below code

```
 <?php foreach ($websites as $websites): ?>
    <?= $this->Html->image('websites/'.$websites->image) ?> 
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: still i cant view the image being uploaded.

Comment: Did you uploaded your image ? Add your code which you have been tried.

Comment: see below for my code thanx..   https://gist.github.com/distromob/911e9f1bc4030de855c1c3d7f3876fe2

Comment: Oh ! Your are not following MVC pattern, see this example It may help you.
https://bitbucket.org/pitocms/cakephp-3-image-upload/src/e15ffe3b7dd4abba051cfc60043342bffddef189?at=master

Comment: i got this error when i copied the code above   "Cannot validate mimetype for a missing file"       But only the image is saved not the entire rows..

Comment: I just commented temporary the validation on image field and it working fine,, Can you help me @Alimon Karim on how to display the images inserted in each row from the database, i followed your code on bitbuket.. Thank you ahead